# How to use TOP() in Conjunction with Table Function

Tags: sql-server, table-functions

I am trying to do some thing like this:

```
Select top 10 * from dbo.Fn_getUsers( ) where some condidtion
```

The problem is taht it is giving an error message:

```
incorrect synatax near from
```

How to make this work. Please help.

Comment: A `select top 10 * from dbo.fn_tvf() where...` works for me. What version of SQL Server do you have? Does the query work without `TOP 10` ?

Comment: @OcasoProtal..yeah its working fine..Stupidly i missed * in my actual query in confusion..:(